# Save and load status of toggle button

Tags: android, button, load, save, toggle

I'm trying to save the status of a toggle button, that I've create dynamically. I'm not able to save the current status. If I change activity in my application and then come back the toggle button's status is back to default. Here is my code. Can someone help me?

```
private class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>>
{


    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, 
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> Strings){
        super(context,textViewResourceId, Strings);
    }

    List<Paper> papers_list = BetterActivity.masterConference.getPapers();


    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView paperTitle, author;
    }



    ViewHolder viewHolder;



    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent){


        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.paper_row_item, null);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.paperTitle=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.paperTitle);
            viewHolder.author=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.author);
            addFavorite=(ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        viewHolder.paperTitle.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("title").toString());
        viewHolder.author.setText(searchResults.get(position).get("author").toString());

        LoadPreferences();

        final List<Paper> pape = masterConference.getUser().getFavoritePapers();

        addFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            Paper p = papers_list.get(position);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();
                System.out.println(parent.getChildAt(position).getId() + " " + position);
                SharedPreferences preference = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                if(on)
                {
                    masterConference.addPaperToFavorites(p);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(p.getTitle(),true);
                    editor.commit();
                    //SavePreferences(p.getTitle(), position);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "esta verde, " + p.getTitle() + "size " + pape.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    masterConference.removePaperFromFavorites(p);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preference.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(p.getTitle(),false);
                    editor.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "esta branco", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }
}  
private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    for(int i = 0; i < papers_list.size(); i++)
    {
    String epa = papers_list.get(i).getTitle();
    boolean teste = preferences.getBoolean(epa, false);

    if(teste == true)
        addFavorite.setChecked(true);
    else
        addFavorite.setChecked(false);
    }

}
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I save and load but this does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just pass the state of the ToggleButton to your next Activity before starting it? Or make it a global static member, but this won't be much help if the Activity gets destroyed and recreated. Might want to just store the state of the button in SharedPreferences and access it anywhere you like.